# In Github action, can I set a condition to initialize a step input

Tags: github, github-actions

I'd like to know if there is a way to set a GHA input in a workflow on a condition, otherwise use the default value.
Here is a example bellow to illustrate my problem.

I use this simple Github action to check the behavior of input:

```
name: 'Test Input'
description: 'Test input values'

inputs:
  my-input-with-default:
    description: 'Input with a default'
    default: 'default value'
    required: false

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Test Input with default
      if: ${{ inputs.my-input-with-default }}
      shell: bash
      run: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        set -euo pipefail
        echo "my-input-with-default: '${{ inputs.my-input-with-default }}'"
```

I call it using this workflow:

```
name: Test Input for Gitub Action

on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      my-input-dispatch:
        description: 'Test input'
        required: false
        default: ''

jobs:
  my-test:
    runs-on: toolbox-runner
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Test gh action 5
      uses: ./.github/actions/test-input
      with:
        my-input-with-default: ${{ inputs.my-input-dispatch != '' && inputs.my-input-dispatch }}
```

What I'd like to do would be to set the `my-input-with-default` input in the action only if the `my-input-dispatch` input from the workflow is not empty.

Using

```
my-input-with-default: ${{ inputs.my-input-dispatch != '' && inputs.my-input-dispatch }}
```

Doesn't work as it sets `my-input-with-default` to `'false'` if `my-input-dispatch` is empty.

I could use

```
my-input-with-default: ${{ inputs.my-input-dispatch != '' && inputs.my-input-dispatch || 'default value' }}
```

But it adds a unwanted dependency between the workflow and the action.

Is it possible to achieve this without duplicating a step with a condition?

Comment: Why not doing the check in the composite action? The first step could be to check if the `my-input-with-default` is empty or not, and set the **default value** if not empty to use afterwards.

Comment: @GuiFalourd good suggestion but this means I wouldn't be able to set `my-input-with-default` to an empty value (which can happen in my case ...).

Comment: Following what you currently use, you could also be checking if the input value is `false` in your composite action (instead of checking if the input is empty).